# How to assign an empty set to a record using overloaded operators

Tags: delphi, set, operator-overloading

I'm using a record to encapsulate two dissimular sets.
I've put in operators to allow the assignment of either set to the record. Doing so will clear the other set.
However I cannot assign an empty set.

See the following example code:

```
Program test;

{$Apptype console}
type
  TSomeThing = (a,b,c);
  TOtherThing = (x,y,z);
  TSomeThings = set of TSomething;
  TOtherThings = set of TOtherThing;

  TSomeRecord = record
  strict private
    Fa: TSomeThings;
    Fb: TOtherThings;
  public
    class operator Implicit(a: TSomeThings): TSomeRecord;
    class operator Implicit(a: TOtherThings): TSomeRecord;
  end;

implementation

class operator TSomeRecord.Implicit(a: TSomeThings): TSomeRecord;
begin
  Result.Fa:= a;
  Result.Fb:= [];
end;

class operator TSomeRecord.Implicit(a: TOtherThings): TSomeRecord;
begin
  Result.Fa:= [];
  Result.Fb:= a;
end;

var
  SomeRec: TSomeRecord;

begin
  SomeRec:= [];
end.
```

> [dcc64 Error] InstructionList.pas(512): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TSomeRecord' and 'Set'

How do I make it so I can assign the empty set to my record?
I can misuse the implicit operator to allow `SomeRec:= nil;`, but that looks very ugly.

Comment: Compiler cannot recognize what the `[]` is. Is that `TSomeThings` or `TOtherThings` ? Even we can't say. Only you know what you were about to assign there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler cannot tell whether you mean an empty set of `TSomeThing` or an empty set of `TOtherThing`. You can declare typed constants to allow the compiler to resolve the overload:

```
const
  EmptySomeThings: TSomeThings = [];
  EmptyOtherThings: TOtherThings = [];
```

Then the following assignments compile and resolve as you would expect:

```
SomeRec:= EmptySomeThings;
SomeRec:= EmptyOtherThings;
```

Of course, you know that either one of these has the same effect, because the implementation of the `Implicit` operators sets one field, and clears the other. But the compiler cannot know this.

If you wish to clear both members of the record you can always use:

```
SomeRec:= Default(TSomeRecord);
```

I personally might wrap that up in a static class method like this:

```
class function Default: TSomeRecord; static;
....
class function TSomeRecord.Default: TSomeRecord;
begin
  Result := Default(TSomeRecord);
end;
```

Then you can write:

```
SomeRec:= TSomeRecord.Default;
```

In an ideal world you'd be able to declare a constant in the type, but the language designers did not think of that and it is sadly not possible.

**Update**

Rudy correctly points out in a comment, that constants can be added to a record type by way of a record helper. This was news to me as I mistakenly believed that helpers could only add methods. This is what I love about Stack Overflow. Even when you think you know something pretty well, there's always scope for more knowledge to be acquired. Thanks Rudy.

So you might write:

```
type
  TSomeRecordHelper = record helper for TSomeRecord
  public
    const
      Default: TSomeRecord = ();
  end;
```

Comment: Somehow it feels weird that `default()` is allowed to write to strict private members. I'm sure the feeling will pass. I would shorten your last line to: `SomeRec.Clear` using an inline method.

Comment: @Johan `Default` is not writing to anything - it is creating a default, initialized, instance of the type.  The compiled application needs to be able to do this, for example, to allocate and initialize class fields during construction.  If you're concerned about the assignment of the record copying the private members of that record... well, records are value types.  How else could assignment work if not to copy the record's members?

Comment: @Johan I would strongly recommend that you don't add methods to a value type that mutate its value. That's a known anti-pattern. Assignment is your friend here.

Comment: @Johan So, suppose you made a `TList<TSomeRecord>`. You might then be tempted to write: `List[i].Clear`. Well, that's not going to do anything of use. All it does is clear the temporary, and leave the content of the list unchanged.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  No apologies.  Some days you get the bear...some days the bear gets you ;)

Comment: I am not 100% sure and don't have the time to check right now, but IIRC from a certain Delphi version on, you can use a record helper to sneak the record constants in after the type has been defined.

Comment: Ok, I had some time. I tried and it works. You can define constants in a class helper. Error insight does not like it, but it works in XE4.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Wow! News to me, and you are bang on. Thank you.

Comment: Wow! You answered almost before I had posted my last comment.

Comment: Re the assignment issues, I have a very valid point. This is where the blurring of the lines between reference and values types gets really confusing.

Comment: Can't test right now, but I'd try `const EmptySomeThings = TSomeThings([]);` instead of `const EmptySomeThings: TSomeThings = [];`.

Comment: @Uli Don't think that compiles

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm sure it doesn't compile.

Comment: @J... I could test it now too and of course you're right. Sorry for the diversion.